# Why does it say I don't have enough disk space when I actually do when trying to download Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, xubuntu

I am trying to download Xubuntu 18.04 and this appears:

[You need at least 8.4 GB disk space to install Xubuntu

This computer has only 6.3 GB][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNQCg.png)

I have went to my computer and have seen I actually 141 GB of free space.

[141 GB free of 476 GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsalQ.png)
Since I'm new to this, is there something I'm missing? Maybe Im looking at the wrong place?

Thank you! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "download"? Did you want to say "install"?

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that has passed it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April 2021)

Comment: Also note - that disk space is already used (*being allocated to your windows partition*).  You need to use space that isn't currently used by an OS.  If you have *fastboot*, *hibernate* etc. activated in windows - it cannot be touched by another OS; so is the file-system dismounted?  (*if you're trying to use it using auto-resize or install-alongside*)

Comment: oh my gosh how did i not notice i was installing an old version...thank you!

Comment: FYI:  18.04 tells you it was the 2018-April release given the *year.month* format used by Ubuntu releases (*2000 is added to the year*).   Five years of support applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server.. or key Ubuntu products, three years of support though for *flavors*. The parts of the Xubuntu 18.04 LTS system that are identical to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop (*a sizeable part*) are still supported; jump to a terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm what parts are *supported* on the current system..  (it works on installed systems, and I suspect *live* too)

Comment: ok thank you! It works now :)